# Pause loop that is sending emails

Tags: php, function, symfony, loops, action

I'm trying to send emails to my subscribers list by fetching emails from the database 10 at a time. I want to be able to pause and resume sending those emails with a controller action.

Is there any way in Symfony (or maybe this is a general PHP question) to control a controller action with another action? Something like this:

```
public function sendEmailAction() 
{
    // loop through recipients and send emails
}

public function pauseEmailAction()
{
    // pause the loop in sendEmail
}

public function resumeEmailAction() 
{
    // resume sendEmailAction from the point where 
    // pauseEmailAction has stopped it
}
```

Comment: please anyone can help me on this !

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "control" and by "stop processing firstAction". Actions are methods, they execute themselves till the `return` or till an Exception is thrown. If you want another method to execute before the action is over, just call it through `$this->secondAction()` Or could you explain your use case better plz ?

Comment: @Sogara Thank you, I've edited my post

Comment: Improve question clarity and grammar

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but this should be enough to match your needs.

```
public function firstAction()
{
    for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        $users = $this->giveMeTenUsers($i);
        $this->secondAction($users);
    }
}

public function secondAction(array $users)
{
    // do stuff like send the emails

    return;
}
```

When `firstAction` calls `secondAction`, the execution of `firstAction` is "stopped", waiting for the result of `secondAction`. When `secondAction` hits `return;`, it ends his own execution, and thus sends back the program to `firstAction`, inside the loop where it was called.

Is that what you need? Or is there an element I did not get?

**EDIT:** Why don't you try to set a boolean value to interrupt or not?

Like this:

```
public function mainAction() // firstAction
{
    for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        while ($this->isInterrupted()) {}
        $users = $this->giveMeTenUsers($i);
        // Do stuff
    }
}

public function interruptAction() // secondAction
{
    $this->setInterrupted(true);
}

public function releaseAction() // thirdAction
{
    $this->setInterrupted(false);
}
```

**EDIT 2:** And by the way, you don't have to use Actions, it works with any kind of methods.

**EDIT 3:** Add in your class

```
private $interrupted = false;

public function isInterrupted()
{
    return $this->interrupted;
}

public setInterrupted(bool $interrupted)
{
    $this->interrupted = $interrupted;
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that I wanna run the `firstAction` again using the `thirdAction`, & the `secondAction` will return the id of last suscribers my message has been sent to him before stoping it, so this may not work sorry.

Comment: That seems pretty complex to me for a simple batch processing. Usually batch processing is done the way I answered you with only a few changes. Can you explain me what are your different actions and what they are supposed to do ?

Comment: Just to not determinate the delay of pausing the sending.. for example if I wanted to modify the message for the 15 last contacts I'll be able to take my time in editing.. & resume the sending whenever I want

Comment: Ok I understand a bit more. I'll edit my answer with an idea you can use.

Comment: What do you mean please by this : 
" you don't have to use Actions, it works with any kind of methods."

Comment: You asked if there was a general solution for PHP. Well this is. Not only reserved for Symfony actions.

Comment: Gotcha @sogara, but can you explain me more about this `$this->isInterrupted()` how can I declare it please?

Comment: Edited again, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Sogara :), If it won't help I'll take a look at the Symfony Process, it seems good

Comment: This won't work. In the process that runs mainAction(), the $interrupted variable can't ever get set to true. If another parallel process calls setInterrupted(true), the process that's running the email loop will never see it. You need to persist the interrupt variable in some shared storage space somewhere, like a session or database.